# How to write doubleprime in latex

Tags: symbols

Now I use `f^{\prime \prime}` for double prime. I feel that there should be a better way, but I cannot find how to do it in google or stackexchange. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `f''(x)` will do (any number of apostrophes is allowed.

Answer (score 25):

The easiest version of course is just to use `$f''(x)$` as egreg mentioned in comments. This is supported by pdfLaTeX and really easy to type.

The prime, double prime, and triple prime have their own unicodes [U+2032](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2032/index.htm), [U+2033](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2033/index.htm), and [U+2034](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2032/index.htm) which you could address with help of the package `fontspec` via `\symbol{"2032}...`.

This will require Xe- or LuaLaTeX. However, in this case I would recommend the package `unicode-math` which has all three unicodes wrapped in their own macros. They are easy to type, easy to understand, less bold than the standard version, and have a better (subjectively) kerning to the following parenthesis. The MWE shows the normal and the `unicode-math` way:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    $f'(x)$\\
    $f\prime(x)$\\  
    $f''(x)$\\
    $f\dprime(x)$\\
    $f'''(x)$\\
    $f\trprime(x)$\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to stick to pdfLaTeX, you may define your own commands of course. This could look like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\myprime}{^{\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
\newcommand*{\mydprime}{^{\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
\newcommand*{\mytrprime}{^{\prime\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    $f'(x)$\\
    $f\myprime(x)$\\    
    $f''(x)$\\
    $f\mydprime(x)$\\
    $f'''(x)$\\
    $f\mytrprime(x)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For triple, it is `trprime` or `tprime`? For double, it is `dprime`, not `dbprime`!

Comment: @Sigur As shown in my MWE, which compiles. `dprime` and `trprime`. The custom macros can be named as you please, of course. And if you think, `dbprime` or `tprime` would be a better choice, you should address that [here](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3AFeature).

Comment: `unicode-math` is supposed to use the correct glyph for multiple primes if they're present in the math font. The fact it doesn't seems like a bug.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful! In the end I used f''(x) in pdflatex. As I use lyx, f'(x) and f^\prime(x) look different in lyx, but they look the same in pdf, and f''(x) looks much better than f^{\prime \prime}(x) in pdf.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the same as in the previous case by using insead of "newcommand" "declaremathoperator" on that place I thing it is little bit more straightforward... this is for example for double prime

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\dprime}{\prime \prime}
\begin{document}
$f''(x)$\\
$f^\dprime(x)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm sorry, but this is the wrong way. Much more simply, `\newcommand{\dprime}{{\prime\prime}}` would allow `$f^\dprime(x)$`. I still think that `$f''(x)$` is the way to go.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator` is not the same as `\newcommand`; it changes the spacing.