# Problem with newcommand subscrip doubleprime

Tags: subscripts, scalerel

Some time ago I wrote a command that I used many times, today I realize that it could be written correctly. in particular, the command is selected as "not in a mathematical environment".
I looked for [other solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210290/how-to-write-doubleprime-in-latex/210300) but I do not like them.

I see writing pleasant, but can this command create problems? could you give me a suggestion to write it correctly? Thank you

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mwe} 

\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\scale[2]{\vstretch{#1}{\hstretch{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand\ssp[1]{#1^{\scale{.8}{\scriptstyle{\prime}}}} 
\newcommand\sspp[1]{#1^{\scale{.8}{\scriptstyle{\prime\prime}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{align}
    \ssp{z_G}\\
    \sspp{z_{G}}
    \end{align}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{align}
    \ssp{G}\\
    \sspp{G}
    \end{align}
\end{minipage}\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to redefine your math alphabet with smaller scripts, rather than trying to scale each invocation of a script?

Comment: @Steven I am very inexperienced, could you give me an example? thanks

Comment: why not use the standard definitions? `\newcommand\ssp[1]{#1'} \newcommand\sspp[1]{#1''}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle a question of size. using the `\scale` command I found a nice size for reading and for printing. the problem is certainly the unspecified command in the proper way and the position of the quotes in some conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked in a comment: "Wouldn't it be easier just to redefine your math alphabet with smaller scripts, rather than trying to scale each invocation of a script?"  The OP asked how.

`\DeclareMathSizes` is the command that you can define math script sizes, etc.  Take this basic code and look at the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\centering
\[
z'_G\quad z''_{G_G}\quad G'\quad G''
\]
Inline: $\frac{x}{y}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now (I'm not sure I am setting all the parameters correctly), compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{5}{4}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{6}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\centering
\[
z'_G\quad z''_{G_G}\quad G'\quad G''
\]
Inline: $\frac{x}{y}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The script sizes are smaller.  Also, the `lmodern` package allows for the rendering of the very small math sizes, so you will need that.

Comment: Elegant solution is much more comfortable. there are many things to learn

Comment: @Antonio See this question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8434/how-to-scale-math-font-only, for more details.

Comment: in order to reduce some superscript and subscript I had to create some personal commands. using the media you showed me can greatly reduce the number of personal commands.

Comment: @Antonio Glad to have helped.